AWS CloudWatch - Logs Insights - Adding custom time series labels
On a query like the below, how do I add custom labels when visualizing as bars.
filter @message ~= /errorType1/ or @message ~= /errorType2/ or @message ~= /errorType3/
| fields @message ~= /errorType1/ as errorType1, @message ~= /errorType2/ as errorType2, @message ~= /errorType3/ as errorType3
| stats count() as `By error type` by errorType1, errorType2, errorType3

I was expecting to see at the bottom of each bar the name of the custom fields but the three bars shows labels as in '1_0_0', '0_1_0' and '0_0_1'
See the image...
enter image description here
